# Get customer from save event observer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.0.4

I've just started with Magento 2, but I have few question why try to get customer data from event observer.

Here is what I'm using inside my observer. And the event is `adminhtml_customer_save_after`

`$this->_xmlGenerator->saveCustomerToXml($observer->getEvent()->getCustomer());`

It is return an object from `Magento\Customer\Model\Data`. And this make my concernation. I can't find anything related to something like `getPhone()` inside the codebase.

And how to get specified address from `getAddresses()`

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but if you want the customer from the event adminhtml_customer_save_after then I suggest You try this code in your observer

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
*/
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
```

You can access attributes like addresses with this:

```
$customer->getAddresses();
```

I hope this is the answer you were searching for.

Answer (score 1):

in your observer write below code

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customerData = $event->getCustomer();

foreach ($customerData->getAddresses() as $address)
{
      //addresses
}
```