# Get the user in `catalog_product_save_after` observer

Tags: magento2, catalog, user

In Magento2.1, I create a observer use the event `catalog_product_save_after`, how can I get the user who saved the product in the observer.

The way in [Get customer from save event observer Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109026/get-customer-from-save-event-observer-magento-2) doesn't work, because it used different event.

`$user = $observer->getCustomer()->getData();` doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session** in the **__construct**, then use `$this->authSession->getUser()` to get the user, it will work. Other solution is welcome to post :)

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        Session $authSession
    )
    {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $user = $this->authSession->getUser();
        $userId = $user->getId();
        $userName = $user->getUsername();
        // other codes
    }
}
```